# Create a dynamic table of records, android?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I need to add at least 10 tables in my application to show some statistics to the user.

The data of the table comes from the server side even the table headers.
Instead of creating 10 different tables I am looking for an approach where I can reuse the table. Changing the size at runtime.

[image: Table]

In what data structure should I store the table values and then display in the table?

All I end up doing was this

For header

```
   static void header() {
    TableRow tb_head = new TableRow(c);
    for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(c);
        tv1.setText(row.get(i));
        tb_head.addView(tv1);
    }
    table.addView(tb_head);
}
```

For table values

```
static void tableValues()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.size()-1; i++) {
        TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(c);

        for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(c);
            String s1 = Integer.toString(i);
            String s2 = Integer.toString(j);
            String s3 = s1 + s2;
            int id = Integer.parseInt(s3);
            tv1.setId(id);

            tv1.setText("TextView  no:     " + id);
            tbrow.addView(tv1);
        }

        table.addView(tbrow);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.